# Unable to display jevent modules when a site is visited but not logged on

Tags: joomla-4.x, jevents

When a user is logged into my site he can see and update all events and see then calendar module.  When we have a guest user like most of the users they can't display the calendar.  Joomla 4.2.9. I have played with all types of users and permissions

When I try to access the calendar I get *This page isn’t working right now xxx.org redirected you too many times.
To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  I cleared the cookies many times*

If I click on a module all I see is *You don't have permission to access this. Please contact a website administrator if this is incorrect.*

**How do I set user access and permissions so my guest users can see the calendar**

Comment: Can you provide a URL of your Jevent frontend page and a screenshot of your menu  item settings from admin? Have you published the menu item and set it to public?